# How to color diff output?

Tags: bash, ksh, colors, diff

I wanted to format the Unix files conditionally, I am currently working on `diff` command and wanted to know if it is possible to format the text of the `diff` command output.

Example:

> Matched values should be displayed in green.
>   Unmatched values should be displayed in red.

Suppose I have two files `file1` and `file2` and my command is `diff file1 file2`.

Now I wanted that suppose output contain 5 mismatch then those mismatch should be  displayed in Red color. How to achieve this using unix?

In short "Change color to red for the output of diff command for values which mismatch"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8800578/colorize-diff-on-the-command-line)

Comment: The terms "match" and "mismach" are a bit confusing. Anyway, there's the --color option now in diff 3.4 and later.

Answer (score 99):

**`diff --color` option was added to [GNU diffutils 3.4 (2016-08-08)](https://savannah.gnu.org/forum/forum.php?forum_id=8639)**

This is the default `diff` implementation on most distros, which will soon be getting it.

Ubuntu 18.04 has `diffutils` 3.6 and therefore has it.

On 3.5 it looks like this:

[image]

Tested:

```
diff --color -u \
  <(seq 6 | sed 's/$/ a/') \
  <(seq 8 | grep -Ev '^(2|3)$' | sed 's/$/ a/')
```

Apparently added in commit c0fa19fe92da71404f809aafb5f51cfd99b1bee2 (Mar 2015).

**Word-level diff**

Like `diff-highlight`. Not possible it seems, feature request: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/diffutils-devel/2017-01/msg00001.html

Related threads:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1721738/using-diff-or-anything-else-to-get-character-level-diff-between-text-files
- [diff within a line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11128/diff-within-a-line)
- https://superuser.com/questions/496415/using-diff-on-a-long-one-line-file

`ydiff` does it though, see below.

**`ydiff` side-by-side word level diff**

https://github.com/ymattw/ydiff

Is this Nirvana?

```
python3 -m pip install --user ydiff
diff -u a b | ydiff -s
```

Outcome:

[image]

If the lines are too narrow (default 80 columns), fit to screen with:

```
diff -u a b | ydiff -w 0 -s
```

Contents of the test files:

a

```
1
2
3
4
5 the original line the original line the original line the original line
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15 the original line the original line the original line the original line
16
17
18
19
20
```

b

```
1
2
3
4
5 the original line teh original line the original line the original line
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15 the original line the original line the original line the origlnal line
16
17
18
19
20
```

**`ydiff` Git integration**

`ydiff` integrates with Git without any configuration required.

From inside a git repository, instead of `git diff`, you can do just:

```
ydiff -s
```

and instead of `git log`:

```
ydiff -ls
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7669963/how-can-i-get-a-side-by-side-diff-when-i-do-git-diff/14649328#14649328

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04, git 2.18.0, ydiff 1.1.

Comment: Excellent! To enable this by default:  `alias diff='diff --color=auto'`

Comment: [Here](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/diffutils.html#index-color_002c-distinguishing-different-context) is the documentation.

Comment: does not work on Centos 7

Comment: @user5359531 what's the diff version?

Comment: looks like 3.3 unfortunately

Comment: I also couldn't get this to work on ubuntu 18.04 running on WSL accessed with Windows Terminal 2. Adding the --color=[always/auto] command didn't make a difference to the output.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31356602/4857270) also shows a way to use `git diff` to accomplish the same: 
`git diff --no-index --word-diff=color --word-diff-regex=. file1 file2`

Comment: Does anyone know why the color gets lost if I pipe to `more`? Or how to fix this behavior? (or a better way to slowly scroll through the `diff` output?)

Comment: @TylerR. see: https://superuser.com/questions/117841/when-reading-a-file-with-less-or-more-how-can-i-get-the-content-in-colors

Comment: seems like `diff --color=auto` does not work when `-y` flag is given

Answer (score 28):

If you have access to GNU `diff` you can use its [`--X-group-format` options](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Line-Group-Formats.html#Line-Group-Formats) to get that effect without any additional tools:

```
diff --old-group-format=$'\e[0;31m%<\e[0m' \
     --new-group-format=$'\e[0;31m%>\e[0m' \
     --unchanged-group-format=$'\e[0;32m%=\e[0m' \
     file1 file2
```

That uses [ANSI colour escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors) to get red and green, with [ANSI-C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) in the shell to access the `\e` escapes.

`--old-group-format` and `--new-group-format` identify non-matching lines and insert them between red and colour reset codes using `%<` and `%>`, while `--unchanged-group-format` inserts matching lines between green and reset codes.

You can also [use `--old-line-format`](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Line-Formats.html#Line-Formats) (etc), at the expense of redundant colour escapes on every line: `--old-line-format=$'\e[0;31m%L\e[0m'`.

Comment: when I run it gives diff: 0653-821 illegal option -- -
diff: 0653-821 illegal option -- o
diff: 0653-821 illegal option -- d
diff: 0653-821 illegal option -- -
diff: 0653-821 illegal option -- g
diff: 0653-821 illegal option -- o like errors.

Comment: Hormer when i am running your commands as by one line at a time  it  is giving new line no output -bash-4.2$ --new-group-format=$'\e[0;31m%>\e[0m' \
>

Comment: May I configure that by default?

Comment: @EugenKonkov You could set up an alias or function in your shell to run that for `diff`.

Comment: This gave me a bit of trouble trying to get it to work. Unchanged stuff was showing up as added... gave up and installed colordiff

Comment: @BrianPeterson Isn't that because the suggested solution shows changed lines in red (both old and new stuff) and unchanged lines in green, while we are used to red meaning "old/removed", green meaning "new/added" and white/default color meaning "unchanged"? I've also been confused by this...

Comment: When I pipe the output into `less`, I have to use `--old-line-format` rather than `--old-group-format` to get proper colouring of multi-line changes.

Comment: @Ansa211 That is what the question asked for, rather than traditional colordiff-style output, but you can shift the green escape (32) into `--new-group-format` and drop the unchanged entry entirely to get that (though `diff --color` or colordiff is almost certainly better now if you don't have those very specific requirements - and it uses line-by-line colouring so `difff --color ... | less -R` doesn't break it).

Comment: This worked perfectly for me!

Comment: This was the solution for me on RHEL 8

Answer (score 13):

Try `colordiff file1 file2`

> **Availability of colordiff with your Linux/BSD distribution**
>
> Those running Debian or Ubuntu (or any of their derivatives) can probably
> just use "apt-get install colordiff" to download and install;
> colordiff is also packaged for a number of other Linux, UNIX and BSD
> distributions and operating systems.

(Quote from http://www.colordiff.org/)

Comment: Perfect. For me, `diff --color=auto` was only colourising line markers and the first line of each `+`/`-` section. Piping to `less -SR` makes for easy browsing.

Answer (score 10):

if you have vim installed, you can do `diff file1 file2 | vim -`

Vim will recognise diff format and give it proper coloring. The dash at the end is to let vim accept input from diff command.

Comment: 'view' (the read-only shortcut to vim) is better suited for this purpose.

Comment: this completely wrecked my terminal

Answer (score 7):

**Coloured, *word-level* `diff` ouput**

Here's what you can do with the the below script and [diff-highlight](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/diff-highlight):

[image: Coloured diff screenshot]

```
#!/bin/sh -eu

# Use diff-highlight to show word-level differences

diff -U3 --minimal "$@" |
  sed 's/^-/\x1b[1;31m-/;s/^+/\x1b[1;32m+/;s/^@/\x1b[1;34m@/;s/$/\x1b[0m/' |
  diff-highlight
```

<sub>(Credit to [@retracile's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16865578/5353461) for the `sed` highlighting)</sub>

Comment: Actually, `diff-highlight` does not do a word-level output. It just detects a common prefix and a common suffix on a changed line. For instance, if several words are changed, it will highlight everything from the first changed word to the last changed word. Moreover, this is effective only when only one line is changed between unchanged lines. In GNU Emacs, diff-mode does much better.

Comment: Installation: pip3 install --user diff-highlight

Answer (score 4):

Character-level color diff:
Install [ccdiff](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::ccdiff)

```
ccdiff -r /usr/share/dict/words /tmp/new-dict
```

[image: Output of ccdiff]

Comment: That's the best answer so far. It's not C native, but does the job.

Comment: `ccdiff` seems to work well as a diff program, but unfortunately, it cannot color an existing diff (such as a patch).

Answer (score 3):

You could use :

1. `diff --color=auto file1 file2`
2. `colordiff file1 file2`
3. `git diff file1 file2` which is my favorite method

I currently use `git diff` or pipe it's output with `colordiff` :

`diff() { git diff --no-index "$1" "$2" | colordiff; }`

Comment: I like `git diff --no-index` too but I think files need to be seekable.  (At least, doesn't work with bash process substitution for me)

Comment: @Karl Figure that part out yourself, maybe there is a Terminal setting that does it (or) some other way to make it seekable. I've been using `git diff` from a long time and the file is seekable for me, otherwise there'd be no use of me doing it right.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear very clear.  As a (silly) example, this works for me `diff --color <(ls | head -n+3) <(ls | tail -n +5)` but not with `git diff`.  Admittedly, not a common case or too hard to work around.

Comment: `git diff --no-index` already colorizes the output, why on earth do you pass the output to `colordiff`? If the output has no color then you have wrong config, use `git config color.diff auto` to fix it

Comment: @phuclv at the time which is 2018, I think whatever terminal I was using was not coloring it with `git diff` itself or the color scheme might have been weird without the `colordiff` pipe.

Answer (score 3):

To change diff's color palette use the `--palette` option (diff version 3.4 and higher):

```
diff --color=always --palette='ad=1;3;38;5;154:de=1;3;38;5;9' file1 file2
```

Here `ad` and `de` define the color of added and deleted text respectively. For a detailed description of diff options see `man diff` or `info diff`.

Comment: This is extremely flexible. It's nice to know that I can use whatever palette I want. Thanks.

Comment: +1 I was searching for a `--palette` example, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This script uses the standard pre-version 3.4 diff (it should work with any version of diff) and colorizes the output without changing the output format in any way.  It works with the latest version of RHEL (version 7.5) which has GNU diff version 3.3.  Just put it in your ~/bin directory or anywhere else in your path (I suggest calling it "cdiff").

```
#!/bin/bash
file1color="$(tput setaf 1)"
file2color="$(tput setaf 2)"
sepcolor="$(tput setaf 6)"
reset="$(tput sgr0)"
diff $* |sed -e "s/^\\(<.*\$\\)/$file1color\\1$reset/;s/^\\(>.*\$\\)/$file2color\\1$reset/;s/^\\(---\$\\)/$sepcolor\\1$reset/"
```

Comment: And if you don't know off the top of your head what those parms to `tput` mean, do a `man terminfo`

Comment: This saved me! I am on a system with diff 3.3, so it has no `--color` option (nor can I upgrade, or install colordiff, or anything new).  Modifying the --new-line-format and etc. made it hard to keep the *lines* that normal `diff -u` chooses. This solution was exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the `hl` command available on github : `git clone http://github.com/mbornet-hl/hl`
and on : http://www.flashnux.com/notes/page_000022_US.html

`hl` is a Linux command written in C, especially designed to color a text file or the output of a command. You can use up to **42 colors** simultaneously, and use a configuration file to simplify command lines. You can colorize the output of every command that can be piped to another one. And if you know what regular expressions are, it will be very easy for you to use. You can use the `man` page to understand how to use it.
`hl` is very easy to use and to configure. You even can use the *hl_generic* script to colorize commands output without modifying their syntax.
You can, for example, colorize the output of the `diff` command just by typing your usual command :

```
diff file1 file2
```

If you need some help, just send me an e-mail.
Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Just a note: to get the "side-by-side" output you need "--color=always". You can also paginate it with less and retain the colored output:

```
diff -y --color=always file1 file2 | less -R
```

And yet another hint: try to keep the "--color=always" switch at the end. Reason? With dmesg from util-linux 2.27.1:

```
dmesg --human --color=always | less -R    # works
dmesg --color=always --human | less -R    # doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a really neat tool built with python on Github at the moment called `icdiff`. Produces nice coloured outputs which are also “severity” aware. I use it all the time, well worth checking out.

Answer (score 1):

Install Generic Colouriser ([grc](https://github.com/garabik/grc)) and:

```
grc diff file1 file2
```

Available on both Linux and MacOS.

Comment: this didn't do anything for me, on WSL Ubuntu 18.04 using Windows Terminal 2

Answer (score 0):

If you're on an apline linux container and don't want/can't pull down these other tools, this might work in a pinch.

```bsh
RED="\\\033[0;31m"
GREEN="\\\033[0;32m"
OFF="\\\033[0m"
DIFF=$(diff --label "GOT" <(echo "$OUTPUT") --label "EXPECTED" <(echo "$EXPECTED_OUTPUT"))
printf -- "$(echo "$DIFF" | sed "s|^-|$RED-|g" | sed "s|^+|$GREEN+|g" | sed "s|$|$OFF|g")"
```

Here's some sample output.

[image: sample output]

Answer (score 0):

diff 3.4+ can colorize its output in some modes like `diff -u`, `diff -c`.
Also the pure shell script is available https://github.com/ildar-shaimordanov/colordiff.
It does almost the same work as the Perl https://github.com/daveewart/colordiff.