# How to upgrade/update the diff command?

Tags: macos

macOS 10.15 comes with a very old version of the diff command. I've read in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/338960/80391 that version 3.4 contains the `--color` argument.

How can I update the version on macOS so that I can use this newer feature?

Comment: You'll have build it from source and add it to your environment. You can get the source code here: http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/diffutils/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since macOS does not include a package manager, you have to install one if you want newer versions of the tools that come with the OS.
The most popular one these days is [Homebrew](https://brew.sh). [Macports](https://www.macports.org/) is a similar project.

After installing Homebrew, you can install a newer version of `diff` by installing the `diffutils` package:

```bsh
brew install diffutils
```

Of course you can also build everything from source, but using a package manager is easier.