# diff showing only differences inside line

Tags: shell-script, diff

I want to compare lines in two files, but to minimize noise in the output, I want only the actual differences in the lines to be printed.

For instance, given the two files below:

**a.txt**

```
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
```

**b.txt**

```
a B c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
```

*(the difference between them is the case of letter `b`)*

I want the output to be something like:

```
[-b-]{+B+}
```

Currently, the best approach I found was to use `git diff --word-diff`, but it outputs the whole line:

```
a [-b-]{+B+} c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
```

Is there a more direct way to do it, other than manually parsing the output? Also, ideally I would prefer to use something more commonly available than `git diff`, e.g. a POSIX shell tool that would not require the user to install extra packages.

Comment: It would be nice if you used an example where the differences were more visible. I had to squint to see that those two characters are not the same.

Comment: Sorry, I added a note describing the difference between the lines.

Comment: Why not just use `b` and `B` so it's obvious? I understand that this was probably the actual difference, but for purposes of the question you can make it easier.

Comment: I wanted to avoid solutions that would only work on ASCII characters, but since the proposed solution does not depend on it, I changed it. However, I cannot update the answer to reflect the new changes since the edit would be smaller than 6 characters long.

Comment: related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11128/diff-within-a-line

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using [wdiff](https://www.gnu.org/software/wdiff/):

```
$ wdiff -3 a.txt b.txt

======================================================================
 [-b-] {+B+}
======================================================================
```

The `-3` or `---no-common` option will remove words that are common between the two files and only show the differences.

The `===...` banner (and empty lines) may be removed with `grep`:

```
$ wdiff -3 a.txt b.txt | grep -vx '=*'
 [-b-] {+B+}
```

`wdiff` may also read unified `diff` data if you give it the `-d` or `--diff-input` option, for example from `git`:

```
git diff somefile | wdiff -d -3
```

Although `wdiff` is not a POSIX tool, it is commonly available.

Comment: It might be worth noting that if your terminal supports ANSI escapes, you can make wdiff print fancy colored output that's (imo) easier to read with this in your bashrc: `alias wdiff="wdiff -n -w $'\033[30;41m' -x $'\033[0m' -y $'\033[30;42m' -z $'\033[0m'"` (taken from [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/wdiff/manual/html_node/wdiff-Examples.html)).